# Getting Access Token from localhost URL

Tags: c#, winforms, api, authentication, token

I am developing an application using government APIs and when a user logs in, they are redirected to a URL (specific to me) that contains their bearer token. The URL is "http://localhost:8080/gettoken.aspx". How do I get the token using this URL?

I am quite new to authentication and APIs so forgive me if I don't make much sense.

The application is a windows form application written in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the token from the request header. e.g

```
var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```